# How to updating IEnumerable<MyObject> in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list

I have model MyObject and then in the view I have

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.MyObject>
```

and then further down a form :

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @foreach(MyObject m in Model)
    {
        @Html.TextboxFor(x => x.Name)
    }
}

<input type="submit" value="modify" />
```

I am trying to get this in my controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Update(MyObject _myOject)
{
}
```

When I see the source code, all name is repeated and _myObject is not correctly populated

how do I update a list of objects and save them all at once in MVC?

Answer (score 3):

You action method is waiting for a single parameter named _myObject. And you want to update list of objects

try something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(......))
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(MyObject m in Model)
    {
        @Html.TextBox(string.Format("_myObjects[{0}].Name", i), m.Name)
        i++;
    }

    <input type="submit" value="modify" />
}
```

and your action method should look like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Update(IList<MyObject> _myObjects)
{
}
```

then you will be able to update this list at once