# JQuery AJAX Post to Controller data incorrect

Tags: ajax, list, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

My goal is to display a list of Trending Opinions (A custom Model) from the page's model when the page loads. If a user clicks the "Show more Trending Opinions" button, it uses ajax to call a method on a controller that will then retrieve an additional number of items, come back to the page and display them. Then it adds say 20 more. Then they can repeat the process and click it again, etc.

Exactly the same as a normal site does when you click "Show More" on a list of items.

If the way I am approaching this is incorrect and you know of any tutorial (or just out of your head) showing the correct way to do this in MVC 4, please let me know. I am not dead-set on the way I am doing it at the moment, this is just the "correctest" way I have found.

---

I followed the answer to a similar question: [How to Update List<Model> with jQuery in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161409/how-to-update-listmodel-with-jquery-in-mvc-4)

However, the data coming through to my controller is incorrect and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Let me put as much info as I can, because I have no idea where the error may be.

**Model for page (OpinionModel has a few public properties):**

```
 public class IndexModel
{
      public IList<OpinionModel> TopTrendingOpinions { get; set; }
}
```

**The View:**

```
<div id="TrendingOpinions">

            <p>What is trending at the moment</p>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("LoadMoreTrendingOpinions", "AjaxHelper",
             method: FormMethod.Post,
             htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "LoadTrendingOpinionsForm" }))
         {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TopTrendingOpinions)
            <input type="submit" value="Load More Trending Opinions" />  
         }

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#LoadTrendingOpinionsForm').submit(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        type: this.method,
                        data: {
                            topTrendingOpinions: $(this).serialize()
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });

                return false;
            });
</script>
</div>
```

**There is also an EditorTemplate for my model.

The Controller:**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadMoreTrendingOpinions(IList<MyGoldOpinionMVC.Models.OpinionModel> topTrendingOpinions)
    {
       var dataHelper = new Data.DataHelper();
        var moreTrendingOpinions = dataHelper.LoadMoreTrendingOpinions(topTrendingOpinions.LastOrDefault().Id);

       // var partialView = PartialView("../PartialViews/_ListOfPostedOpinion", moreTrendingOpinions);
        return View(moreTrendingOpinions);
    }
```

---

**So here is the order of events:** 
When running the site, the form shows a list of OpinionModels (Using the Editor Template displaying correct data). When I click the SUBMIT button, it goes to the controller (I have a breakpoint) and the data for the "topTrendingOpinions" parameter is a List with one item in it, but that item is null. So in other words, it is not passing through the list that is clearly being used to populate the form.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to get a list to post back to the controller is to build it manually with jquery.  my understanding is this.serialize on a form click is going to try to serialize the whole from which would get very ugly.  How I would do this is

```
<input type="button" class="btnMore" value="Load More Trending Opinions" /> 

$('.btnMore').on('click', function () {
           $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadMoreTrendingOpinions", "AjaxHelper")',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    Id: '@ViewBag.Id'
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    //add results to your table
                }
            });
    });
```

and set the id of the last record sent through the view bag on your controller so you have a reference to go off of for pulling the next chunk.  Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I like your idea, and have got it working, to a point. It works with the ViewBag Id I set when initially loading the page, but then in my ajax call to the controller, I try to set the Id to the new Id, but it never saves it on the View, and the next ajax call just uses the initially set Id.

Comment: In that case I would save the I'd to a hidden field on the form instead of the view bag and see if that helps

Comment: Do you mean doing another ajax call after the first one is successfully returned? I am returning a PartialView that contains the list of new items, so it doesn't allow me to get the Id from that first ajax call.

Comment: Can you add the ID to the model being passed to the partial and set the hidden field that way?

Answer (score 0):

When posting lists you have to be really careful that your inputs are named correctly. If they are not, the default model binder fails to parse them into classes when posted resulting the object being null in the controller.

In your case you are posting a list of models inside a model, but not the whole model. I'd use PartialView instead of editortemplate, just to make working with field names easier. In my example we are posting a list of FooModels contained in IndexModel

Model

```
public class FooModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
public class IndexModel
{
    public IList<FooModel> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoadMoreTrendingOpinions","AjaxHelper",
         method: FormMethod.Post,
         htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "LoadTrendingOpinionsForm" }))
     {
        @Html.Partial("FooModelsPartial", Model.Foos)
        <input type="submit" value="Load More Trending Opinions" />  
     }
```

FooModelsPartial

```
@model IList<FooModel>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Foo)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Bar)
}
```

Notice how we are using for instead of foreach loop. This is because editors in foreach loop are not named correctly. In this case we want our fields to be [0].Foo, [0].Bar, [1].Foo, [1]. Bar etc.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadMoreTrendingOpinions(IList<FooModel> topTrendingOpinions)
    {
        // do something with toptrending thingy

        var model = new IndexModel();
        model.Foos = topTrendingOpinions;

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Now the real question in my opinion is do you really want to post the whole list of models to get bunch of new ones related to one of them? Wouldn't it be more convenient to post the id of opinion you'd want to read more of, returning partialview containing the requested more trending opinions and appending that to some element in the view with jquery?

Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoadMoreTrendingOpinions","AjaxHelper",
         method: FormMethod.Post,
         htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "LoadTrendingOpinionsForm" }))
     {
        <div id="more">@Html.Partial("FooModelsPartial", Model.Foos)</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Load More Trending Opinions" />  
     }
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#LoadTrendingOpinionsForm').submit(function () {
               $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: {
                        id: 1 /* The id of trending item you want to read more of */
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#more").html(result)
                    }
                });

            return false;
        });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadMoreTrendingOpinions(int id)
    {
        var moreTrendingOpinions = dataHelper.LoadMoreTrendingOpinions(id);

        return PartialView("FooModelsPartial", moreTrendingOpinions);
    }
```

Comment: With regards to your question, I would prefer posting just an Id, then returning another chunk of results. The problem I am having is maintaining the last Id every time. I tried to use ViewBag, but it doesn't seem to be saving the latest item from the returned chunk (so I know where to start next time I click 'more')